# Wyeast smack pack activator not activating

Tags: yeast

I am trying to activate a Wyeast activator pack, but the inner nutrient pouch will not break. Thinking about using rubber mallet.

Any useful ideas?

Comment: I usually just get the activator pack in the bottom corner of the yeast bag, and sort of clap together with my palms. However a mallet would likely do. Worse comes to worst- the activator isn't entirely necessary although it does provide some nice nutrient to the yeast.

Comment: @rob, why not turn this comment into an official Answer by copying it down below under "Your Answer".

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen or used these before, YouTube is your friend. here is a video showing some tips https://youtu.be/svrUeZEg1MI

I looked it up as I wanted to know what this was...

Personally, I would never consider using one of these packs when there is absolutely nothing wrong with dumping yeast straight into the mash even without a starter. it been done like this for the age of time without some expensive fancy overpriced 'smack pack'

I found these pouches for 7.99 GBP in the UK, wow that will buy enough yeast that will keep for years to ferment about 40 x 5gal brews = 1600 pints of beer just for the cost of one pouch.

and isn't the point of home brewing

1. to make something yummy
2. to save money
3. to make something to take pride in
4. to make something you know EXACTLY what is in there

further more for someone to say:

"activator isn't entirely necessary" - My point proven right there.

"it does provide some nice nutrient to the yeast" - You only need to add nutrients if your mash is lacking nutrients then you need to look at your mash process/recipe or fermentation has stalled...